# Get List of KafkaConsumers from Consumer Groups

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I can create a `KafkaConsumer` via `KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)`.

I can also get a List of ConsumerGroups via `ListConsumerGroupsResult list = AdminClient.listConsumerGroups()`.

Is there a way to get a `KafkaConsumer` from `ListConsumerGroupsResult`?  From searching via my IDE and online I haven't found such a way but was wondering if anyone in SO community has done this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a `KafkaConsumer` from the consumer groups result.  The `KafkaConsumer` is what you instantiate to connect to Kafka and to consume data.

I'm assuming you want something like the list of active `KafkaConsumer`s at any particular point in time?  In this case, you'd have to look at the metadata stored in Zookeeper, using something like `zkCli.sh` utility from zookeeper, or a Java Zookeeper client like Curator.

Here's a good reference of the data Kafka stores in Zookeeper, from the official Kafka wiki pages:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper

Comment: That's helpful - thanks.  I'm ultimately trying to get at `consumer.metrics()` for all of the consumers but looks like I might need to go a different route (e.g. JMX)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to query ZooKeeper directly, there is a nice GUI you can use to examin consumers, topics, messages, etc. for a Kafka cluster:

https://github.com/HomeAdvisor/Kafdrop/

It has both a GUI and Restful API.

Comment: @RGA How is this a link only answer?

Comment: My mistake. I'll remove the comment. review queue didn't give the context